# What's the best way to use all 4 GPUs on Nvidia A10 for concurrent inferences using PyTorch?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm using Nvidia A10 which has 4 GPUs. I made multiple inferences in parallel. I got responses. When I check the GPU usage, it seems only one GPU has been used. How can I use all 4 GPUs to make the inferences concurrently?

I tried many ways like DataParallel. It's not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you to take a look at [Ray.io](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/). It's easy to use with already existing pytorch code. And you can monitor the use of gpus in a dashboard.